# Why are inaccessible members considered inherited?

Tags: c#, inheritance

The C# spec states:

> The declared accessibility of a base class member does not control
>   whether the member is inherited--inheritance extends to any member
>   that isn't an instance constructor,static constructor,or destructor. 
>   However, an inherited member may not be accessible in a derived type,
>   either because of its declared accessibility or because it is hidden
>   by a declaration in the type itself.

Why is an inaccessible member considered inherited?  Why is such a distinction made/practical?

As a concrete example

```
class A
{
    const string foo = "c";

    internal void DoWork() { }
}

class B: A
{
    const string bar = "d";//renamed to foo does not appear to have a noticeable impact
    B() { bar = foo; }//inaccessible due to protection level

    internal new void DoWork() { }//hide inherited member
}
```

In my mind, at runtime inheritance means sharing state and/or behavior.  In the case of `foo` such a thing does not occur.

It is up to `B` as to whether or not to inherit the behavior of `DoWork()`.  Therefore, `DoWork()` being a member of `B` is intuitive and relevant.  On the other hand, why is `foo` treated as a Member of `B`?  `B` cannot read from or write to `foo`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, you're talking about `const`, which is implicitly static. Static members effectively aren't inherited anyway. Having just checked the spec, that implies that static members *are* inherited - but as they don't represent state and can't be part of polymorphism, it's at least a "different" kind of inheritance. I think of static members as merely being "available via simple name" to derived classes, assuming they're accessible at all - in other words, it's to do with name resolution more than real inheritance.

If this were a private *instance* variable, then it would be part of the state of any instance of an instance of any type derived from `A`, so it *would* be inherited state. If you think about an object's state and behaviour being inherited, it makes sense in my view.

(It's probably worth being clear about whether you're interested in the static part or the private part; they're somewhat orthogonal.)

Comment: I'm more interested in the private part.  The fact that I made this static was just a poor choice.  As noted in the spec, it makes no distinction between static and instance in this section....so I thought the choice was arbitrary.

Answer (score 6):

This article might help you.

http://ericlippert.com/2011/09/19/inheritance-and-representation/

> Why is an inaccessible member considered inherited? Why is such a distinction made/practical?

It would be better to ask the opposite question: why would it be practical to make a rule that says that inaccessible members are not inherited?  Let's consider the consequences of such a rule.

First off, if you have

```
class B
{
  internal int x; 
}
class D1 : B {}
// in another assembly
class D2 : B {}
```

You would say that x is inherited by D1 but not by D2? That seems weird.  Or what about this case:

```
class B
{
  private int x;
  private class D1 : B {}
}
class D2 : B {}
```

Again, you would say that x is inherited by D1 but not by D2?

*In every case, the derived class has an integer field x*, but you would deny that *fact* merely on the basis that the field cannot be accessed by name in some source code locations? What is the compelling value in making a definition of "inherited" that is so tied to the definition of "accessible"?

It is far easier to simply make the two concepts orthogonal. "Inherited" means "this member of the base type is also a member of the derived type". Accessibility is a matter of whether the accessing source code is inside the accessibility domain of the declared member. They have little to do with each other, so let's not conflate them unnecessarily.

Comment: I'm beginning to see a pattern in my ability to get lost in "implementation detail".

Answer (score 2):

This is most easily explained through a demonstration:

```
public class Parent
{
    private int value;
    public virtual int GetValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public int GetOtherValue()
    {
        //"value" is no accessible in this scope
        return GetValue() + 1;
    }
}
```

When an object is created memory is allocated for all of the instance fields for that type.  `Child` actually has 1 instance field, not 0.  `value` is inherited from `Parent` and is an instance field of `Child`.  When you create a `Child` instance, it has it's own value for `value`.  That `value` field isn't accessible in the definition for `Child` though (because it's private); it is only accessible through the methods/properties that `Parent` exposes which *are* accessible.